# Eclipse IDE error

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Olá, pessoal. Alguém sabe me dizer que erros são esses? Diz também "String cannot be resolved to a type", poderia ser problemas com a versão do JDK?

[image: Print da tela com os erros]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que seu projeto não consiga encontrar os runtimes do JRE. 
Isso faria tipo java.lang.String  e outros tipos java.* gerar esse erro.

Se for esse o caso configure o JRE no Eclipse:

Uma vez iniciado o Eclipse clique Janela->Preferências:

[image: Painel do Eclipse Windows->Preferences]

---

Selecione Instalar Java/JRE no painel esquerdo, e pressione o botão `Adicionar...` no painel direito
[image: Instalando JRE]

---

Na página do assistente selecione "Standard VM" e pressione avançar.
[image: Assistente de instalação JRE]

---

Pressione diretório...

[image: Assistente de configuração de instalação]

---

Selecione o caminho para o JDK's.

[image: Asistente de pastas]

Nota: Se a máquina for Win32, o caminho de instalação na falta será `C:\Arquivos de Programas\Java\jdk[versão]`

---

Na próxima página verifique o no do JRE e se as bibliotecas de sistema foram adequadamente reconhecidas pelo Eclipse itself. Então clique em finalizar.

[image: Definições do JRE]

---

Verifique se for criada corretamente a entrada JRE na lista e então pressione Ok.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

fonte: https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/Setting_Default_JRE_In_Eclipse

Comment: Opa, funcionou! Fui colocando as JDK's todas, aí funcionou na 11. Obrigado!